# Ajax and htaccess - Redirecting only content div, making duplicate entire template

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, redirect

I want to use a audio player in my page, but the player can't be reloaded when the page refresh. So, I divided the template in 3 divs: header, content and footer, where the player is. To redirect to another page, I use ajax to refresh only content div. At the same time, I'm using htaccess to redirect everything to index.php, my base template. I'm doing like that to always validade every request, to display the page requested, when exist, or a 404 page when not exist. The problem is when I redirect to any page, for example, "/about". Because the htaccess, the index.php is going to the content div. I want to load my base template in index.php only one time. Is there a workaround for my scenario. I'm dont want to use any information from the client-side, like headers. Just for secury reasons. Below, there's an example of my code:

My index.php

```
<?php

//Creating base template...;

//Here, will be a URI validation
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

?>
```

```
<script>

    $(document).on('click', "a", function(e){

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: document.location.pathname,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(ret) {

                $("#content").html(ret);

            }
        });

        return false;
    });

</script>
```

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="/home">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <h1>Content Here</h1>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <audio controls>
      <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</div>
```

My htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

My about.html page

```
</h1>About Page</h1>
```

Comment: *"player can't be reloaded when the page refresh"* - pretty sure that's unavoidable if the user hits the reload button in their browser. *"validade every request, to display the page requested, when exist, or a 404 page when not exist"* - that's standard behaviour though, why do you need to create a PHP router for that?

Comment: It's just an ideas, but there are other ways to the player still playing after redirect by a link in the page? And there's other better ways to create a simple PHP router for that case? Thx!

Comment: If you're already loading the content into a `<div>` using AJAX from the site navigation then the page won't reload anyway, so the player won't be interrupted. The server will respond with a 404 if a page isn't found so there's no need to do anything with PHP there. If you're using a custom 404 page you can just configure that in Apache itself.

Comment: Yes, if the user enter for the first time, the site navigation will never affect the player. The problem is the htaccess. I want to redirect everything to index, and because of that, the "ajax redirection" load the entire index.php in my content div. The index.php need to return a html page, according to the requested page. But I need to return the header and footer once, when the user enter for the first time in the page. After that, the index.php will return only a html page in the content div.

Comment: You could tailor the response from `index.php` using something like `strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) = 'xmlhttprequest'` so that when that page has a request from AJAX it merely returns the HTML snippet you want to insert into the div - without it it returns the whole shebang.

Comment: It's a way, but I look for some way that doesn't need to use information coming from the client-side, like headers. Just for precaution.

Comment: Is there a way to know if the redirection comes from the URL bar or not?

Comment: Without relying on information from the client? No.

Comment: Well, I think I need to review my strategies and ways I want to use. Thanks for everything!